Retrieving bulk query results from sf cli
I am using @salesforce/cli/2.50.6 win32-x64 node-v20.15.0
I am trying to extract data using a bulk query. This is a significant amount of data in this query request:
C:\Users\{user}\Desktop>sf data query --query "{query}" --target-org {org} --bulk --async
Query ID: {job_id}
Query is in progress.

Run "data query resume -i {job_id} -o {org}" to get the latest status and results.

Total number of records retrieved: 0.
Querying Data... done

I then checked the status of the job:
C:\Users\{user}\Desktop>sf data resume -i {job_id} -o {org}

=== Job Status

id:                      {job_id}
operation:               query
object:                  Account
createdById:             {user_id}
createdDate:             2024-07-24T12:34:14.000Z
systemModstamp:          2024-07-24T12:43:00.000Z
state:                   JobComplete
concurrencyMode:         Parallel
contentType:             CSV
numberBatchesQueued:     0
numberBatchesInProgress: 0
numberBatchesCompleted:  92
numberBatchesFailed:     0
numberBatchesTotal:      92
numberRecordsProcessed:  21165218
numberRetries:           0
apiVersion:              61.0
numberRecordsFailed:     0
totalProcessingTime:     2304433
apiActiveProcessingTime: 2304433
apexProcessingTime:      0
Getting Status... done

Great! It ran successfully. But when I try to extract the data, I receive this information that the resource does not exist:
C:\Users\{user}\Desktop>sf data query resume -i {job_id} -o {org} -r csv  > test.csv
Error (1): The requested resource does not exist


How do I extract these batch results into a csv? Where did the resource go?

Hello @identigral. I am so sorry for whatever happened to you. I hope you find peace and contentment for I know you are built for so much more.
The --async flag returns control immediately to the terminal, so it's expected to return 0 records.

Open an issue on GH. There's a similar issue but without a clear root cause or resolution
